# I did it ( myself or by myself)

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, causatives, prepositional-passive

I found some sentences that in which  ***by*** is not used. Such as:

> - I did it myself .
> - I will kill you myself .
> - he cooks food himself.
>
> Why by isn't used with these sentences like: by myself, by himself?

Answer (score 3):

To *be by yourself* (note the preposition) means to be alone, or to have nobody else with yourself.

> He stood by himself, as he was now completely alone

To *do something yourself* means that you are the only person carrying out a specified action.

> Though the crowd offered their help, she insisted on doing it herself

If someone were to say "he cooks food *by* himself", that would most likely mean that they cook food alone.